# Using ansible to merge object values with the same key in a list of dictionaries variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a list of dictionaries:

```yaml
"users": [
    {
        "name": "bob",
        "attribute": "abc"
    },
    {
        "name": "alice",
        "attribute": "dfg"
    },
    {
        "name": "bob",
        "attribute": "rst"
    },
    {
        "name": "alice",
        "attribute": "xyz"
    }
]
```

I want to merge the object attributes under the same name and remove duplicates so the result would be:

```yaml
"users": [
    {
        "name": "bob",
        "attribute": ["abc", "rst"]
    },
    {
        "name": "alice",
        "attribute": ["dfg", "xyz"]
    }
]
```

So far I've been playing with the `groupby` filter which produces:

```yaml
"users": [
        [
            "alice",
            [
                {
                    "attribute": "dfg",
                    "name": "alice"
                },
                {
                    "attribute": "xyz",
                    "name": "alice"
                }
            ]
        ],
        [
            "bob",
            [
                {
                    "attribute": "abc",
                    "name": "bob"
                },
                {
                    "attribute": "rst",
                    "name": "bob"
                }
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

Now, I guess that I have to merge the object.attribute for every user.

So, how to do that..?, any help would be appreciated :)

In doing so, would it be possible to add a suffix (always the same string) to each attribute so that the result would look like this?:

```
    "my_users": [
        {
            "attribute": [
                "dfg_suffix",
                "xyz_suffix"
            ],
            "name": "alice"
        },
        {
            "attribute": [
                "abc_suffix",
                "rst_suffix"
            ],
            "name": "bob"
        }
    ]
```

I was able to figure it out so the task looks like:

```
    - set_fact:
        my_users:  "{{ my_users|default([]) +
                       [{'name': my_name,
                         'attribute': my_attribute}] }}"
      loop: "{{ users|groupby('name') }}"
      vars:
        my_name: "{{ item.0 }}"
        my_attribute: "{{ item.1|map(attribute='attribute')|list | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', '\\1_suffix') | list}}"
    - debug:
        var: my_users
```

which produces:

```
"my_users": [
        {
            "attribute": [
                "dfg_suffix", 
                "xyz_suffix"
            ], 
            "name": "alice"
        }, 
        {
            "attribute": [
                "abc_suffix", 
                "rst_suffix"
            ], 
            "name": "bob"
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task below does the job

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_users:  "{{ my_users|default([]) +
                       [{'name': my_name,
                         'attribute': my_attribute}] }}"
      loop: "{{ users|groupby('name') }}"
      vars:
        my_name: "{{ item.0 }}"
        my_attribute: "{{ item.1|map(attribute='attribute')|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_users
```

gives

```yaml
    "my_users": [
        {
            "attribute": [
                "dfg",
                "xyz"
            ],
            "name": "alice"
        },
        {
            "attribute": [
                "abc",
                "rst"
            ],
            "name": "bob"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much!

Comment: Forgive the abuse of confidence but I have edited my question to ask if it would be possible to modify each attribute by adding a fixed suffix.

Comment: I have modified my question to include the solution I found. Thanks again @vladimir-botka, without your help I would never have reached the solution in the first place :)